# How do I combine non-overlapping distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two distributions, one only positive and one only negative. I'm trying to figure out how to combine them mathematically into a combined distribution. For example, I have two log normal distributions: $D_c \sim\ ln ~ \mathcal{N}(\mu_c, \sigma_c) $, $D_e \sim\ ln ~ \mathcal{N}(\mu_e, \sigma_e)$. I would like to combine (NOT the sum) these two distributions into a single distribution $\Delta$ where $D_c$ forms the positive part of $\Delta$ and $D_e$ is reflected over the y-axis to form the negative part of $\Delta$. $D_e$ and $D_c$ will also be scaled by their respective probabilities, p and 1-p. The way I code this combine distribution in R is the following (where M is some large number):

$\Delta_{ln\mathcal{N}} = c(rlnorm(M*p,\mu_c,\sigma_c),-rlnorm(M*(1-p),\mu_e,\sigma_e))$

Any guidance on how I can represent this combined distribution mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, what you want is is [mixture distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). So your final random variable has the same distribution as $D_c$ with probability $p$ and with probability $1-p$ it has the same distribution as $-D_e$.